# Refreshing a particular cell of a grid without loading entire grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, refresh

Is there any way to refreshing a cell of a grid view without refreshing the entire grid view in c# asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could possibly use a templatefield, put an UpdatePanel in it and refresh that single cell that way. You would just need someway to initiate the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use a nested UpdatePanel within the cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put an `UpdatePanel` in *every* cell in your GridView, you can refresh a cell on a regular, full postback. The contents of the grid will be roundtripped, but your data source won't necessarily be queried in full.

First, make sure your grid doesn't rebind on every postback, e.g. wrap your `gv.DataSource = x; gv.DataBind();` inside an `if (!this.IsPostBack)`.

Then you should be able to do something along the lines of

```
((Label)gv.Rows[x].Cells[y].FindControl('myLabel')).Text =
    GetDataItemNumber(x).FieldForColumnY.ToString();
```

Bear in mind that `gv.Rows[x]` may not correspond to the `x`th item in your data source, as `Rows` includes header rows etc. You might need to iterate through `Rows` checking e.g. IDs to find the correct row.

Disclaimer: I've never actually *done* this before, but it should be possible...